# Update Command in Gridview stopped working (used to work before and delete, select works fine)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, gridview

I have a gridview that uses accessdatasource which has select, insert, delete and update. It used to work before perfectly but all of a sudden the update stopped working while the rest are still working as they supposed to be. I haven't changed anything in the gridview or datasource, but I added new fields to the table but are not displayed in gridview. I tested by deleting the new fields from the table which did not work either. Refreshed the datasoure and gridview as well. Here is the code

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
              ShowFooter="True" EmptyDataText="There are no records for the selection"  
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"  OnRowCommand="Insert_Click" 
              OnRowUpdating="beforeUpdate"           
              DataKeyNames="Lab Name,Target,Device Name" 
              ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
              EmptyDataRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
              EmptyDataRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="1333px" 
              DataSourceID="AccessDataSource8">
              <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
              <EmptyDataRowStyle Wrap="False" /> 
              <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                              CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                          &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                              CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                              CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                          &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                              CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" ></asp:LinkButton>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="validate" ></asp:LinkButton>
                     </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lab Name" SortExpression="Lab Name">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Lab Name]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[Lab Name]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtLabname" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LabName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLabname" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate"/>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Target" SortExpression="Target">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Target") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Target") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtTarget" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Target" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTarget" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate"/>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Device Name" SortExpression="Device Name">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Device Name]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[Device Name]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtDevicename" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Devicename" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDevicename" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate"/>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IO Type Requirement" 
                      SortExpression="IO Type Requirement">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" 
                              Text='<%# Bind("[IO Type Requirement]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                              Text='<%# Bind("[IO Type Requirement]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtIotyperequirement" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Iotyperequirement" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtIotyperequirement" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate"/>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part Number" SortExpression="Part Number">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Part Number]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Part Number]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartnumber" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Partnumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPartnumber" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate"/>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Part" SortExpression="Sub Part">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Sub Part]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Sub Part]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubpart" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Subpart" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSubpart" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate"/>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subpart Description" 
                      SortExpression="Subpart Description">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" 
                              Text='<%# Bind("[Subpart Description]") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" 
                              Text='<%# Bind("[Subpart Description]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubpartdesc" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Subpartdesc" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSubpartdesc" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate"/>
                      </FooterTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
              <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" 
                  VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
          </asp:GridView> 

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource8" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" 
                DataFile="~/App_Data/Test.mdb"
                 SelectCommand="SELECT Lab1.[Lab Name], Lab1.[Target], Lab1.[Device Name], Lab1.[IO Type Requirement], Lab1.[Part Number], Lab1.[Sub Part], Lab1.[Subpart Description]
            FROM Lab1 
        WHERE      
         (((Lab1.[Lab Name])= [WhichLab] OR [WhichLab] = '0') AND
        ((Lab1.[Target])= [WhichTarget] OR [WhichTarget] = '0') AND
        ((Lab1.[Device Name])= [WhichDevice] OR [WhichDevice] = '0') AND
        ((Lab1.[IO Type Requirement])= [Whichiotyperequirement] OR [Whichiotyperequirement] = '0') AND
        ((Lab1.[Part Number])= [WhichPartNumber] OR [WhichPartNumber] = '0') AND
        ((Lab1.[Sub Part])= [WhichSubPart] OR [WhichSubPart] = '0') AND
        ((Lab1.[Subpart Description])= [WhichSubPartDesc] OR [WhichSubPartDesc] = '0')
         )" UpdateCommand= " UPDATE  [Lab1] SET  [IO Type Requirement]= ?, [Part Number]= ?, [Sub Part]= ?, [Subpart Description]= ? 
            WHERE ([Lab Name]= ?) AND ([Target]= ?) AND ([Device Name] = ?)"


              InsertCommand= "INSERT INTO LAB1 ([Lab Name],[Target],[Device Name],[IO Type Requirement],[Part Number],[Sub Part],[Subpart Description]) VALUES 
            ([WhichLab],[WhichTarget],[WhichDevice],[Whichiotyperequirement],[WhichPartNumber],[WhichSubPart],[WhichSubPartDesc]) "

            DeleteCommand= " Delete from LAB1 WHERE LAB1.[Lab Name]= [WhichLab] AND Lab1.[Target]=[WhichTarget] AND Lab1.[Device Name]=[WhichDevice]">


                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Lab Name" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="Target" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="Device Name" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="IO Type Requirement" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList5" Name="Part Number" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList6" Name="Sub Part" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList7" Name="Subpart Description" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />                                                                    
                </SelectParameters>


                <UpdateParameters>

                    <asp:Parameter  Name="IO Type Requirement"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Part Number"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Sub Part" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Subpart Description"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Lab Name"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Target" Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Device Name"  Type="String"/>

                </UpdateParameters>

                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Lab Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Target" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Device Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="IO Type Requirement" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Part Number" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Sub Part" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Subpart Description" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Lab Name" Type="String" />
                     <asp:Parameter Name="Target" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Device Name" Type="String" />


                </DeleteParameters>
            </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: CausesValidation="True" might cause?

Comment: I have changed it to false and tested as well but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the fields in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ([Lab Name]= ?) AND ([Target]= ?) AND ([Device Name] = ?)"
```

...is not matching records.  Maybe there are trailing spaces in one or more of the fields.

`"ABC"` will not match  `"ABC           "`

Comment: no there are no spaces I looked into it and I have same issue with other gridview as well, it is just the same functionality but with different table.

Comment: If no records are being updated, and there is no error message, it must be that the WHERE clause isn't finding records.   Or, you are updating database A and then looking in database B.  Or, the database is case sensitive and 'A' does not equal 'a'.

Comment: I tested the update query in OnUpdating method in front end and that works but not through the datasource and one thing select, delete and insert works just fine from the same datasource. I have noticed that if I change the update parameters I mean if I give a wrong name there, that is not throwing an error but if I type something wrong in the query it is throwing an error. So the update parameters is not working, how do I fix that.

Comment: Does the DELETE work?  The WHERE clauses in your UPDATE and DELETE statements are very different.  BTW, things work a lot better when you use a single auto-incrementing int as a primary ID.

Comment: yes DELETE works fine and where clause is same for UPDATE and DELETE, I changed ? symbols similar to DELETE where clause nothing worked. I was thinking of that auto-incrementing key but have to change entire website for that and wierdest part is it used to work just fine before and I did not change a single letter in it.

Comment: I don't know if you updated your post on not so check that the order of the Update parameters match the order they appear in the SQL statement.  Also check that this line is correct:  DataKeyNames="Lab Name,Target,Device Name"

Comment: The order of parameters are correct and the primary keys are also the correct ones. I am wondering why the parameters are ignored completely and does the gridview gets mad when we refresh without changing the columns since I don't use dynamic gridview I don't want to the columns get changed.

Comment: Create a new page.  Drop an Access DataSource on it.  Configure it to point to your database.  Drop a new GridView on it and set it to allow updates.  If it works, you can look for differences in the text generated in the aspx file.

Comment: hey I just found the error, it is because of the spaces and the symbols used in the column names. I had to change the names with out spaces and symbols which works now. Bind function doesnot work for columns which has non-alphanumeric characters. That is the reason update didn't work while delete was fine. Thanks for the help can you update your answer so that I can accept it.